# pipe a buffer from my program to another program's stdin using popen

Tags: c, unix, pipe, popen

Suppose I have a program that, in part, runs another program
using   FILE *outptr=popen("some command string","r")   and then
fread()'s that program's stdout from outptr. Now, if that other program
reads its input from its stdin, and I want
that input to come from file inputfile already on disk, then I could easily
just write   FILE *outptr=popen("cat inputfile|otherpgm","r");

But here's the rub: rather than some inputfile on disk, my
program has an internal   unsigned char buffer[9999]   which is
what I want piped to otherpgm, but which I don't want written
to disk first. How can I get buffer[] piped directly to otherpgm's stdin
using popen()? Or some other mechanism, as long as I can read
otherpgm's stdout from within my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get buffer[] piped directly to otherpgm's stdin using popen()?

This can't be done using `popen`.

> Or some other mechanism

You need to set up two pipes (see [man pipe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)) -- one from your-program to the other-program, and one from other-program to your-program, then `fork`, close appropriate ends of the pipes in the child and `exec` other-program.

You also need to worry about deadlocks if the data you need to write or read exceeds `PIPE_BUF`.

[Example code](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/remap-pipe-fds.html).

[Relevant answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53641/how-to-make-bidirectional-pipe-between-two-programs) -- this can be much easier if you can make a FIFO on disk.

[Another answer](https://coderedirect.com/questions/135076/can-popen-make-bidirectional-pipes-like-pipe-fork) with examples.

Comment: Thanks very much, @EmployedRussian (hope that's gainfully employed:) Your brief description followed by those very useful links really answered the question beautifully. By the way, no deadlock problem, I don't think -- that otherpgm reads all its input from stdin before writing any output to stdout. (P.S. I tried to upvote your answer, too, but apparently don't have enough points myself to do that yet.)